# Parse URL returns incorrect response

Tags: parse-platform, bitnami

I have an installation of the Parse Server powered by Bitnami. I have modified the server.js code, and inserted appropriate keys.

My codebase lies on another instance of AWS, and can be accessed by the following URL: http://34.194.238.134:9000/coaches (hitting the URL http://34.194.238.134 takes the website to the https version, so I am using port 9000 so avoid the https conflict)

However, my data does not load. When I inspect the request (which should bring data from the InstructorClass), it hits the correct URL, but the response gives me something from the Parse Dashboard instead of a JSON response.

The Application keys are embedded into the Request Payload, and are set correctly. Not sure what to do...

[image: Request]

[image: Response]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is likely happening because the requests to Parse in your page are being directed to port 1337 instead of 80. If you retry the `POST` request you show in the screenshots but targeting port 80, you should get this JSON response:

```
{"code":102,"error":"Invalid parameter for query: _ApplicationId"}
```

If you change the request type to `GET` and include the `X-Parse-Application-Id` header with the right value, you should get the JSON data of the object as a response. You may test it with the `curl` command:

```
curl -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" http://ec2-54-165-212-93.compute-1.amazonaws.com/parse/classes/InstructorClass
```

Please, don't forget to replace the `APP_ID` placeholder with the correct value in the previous command.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!!